# How can be Highchart width and height be responsive in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I am using **Highcharts** to draw a bar chart but it's width is not responsive at all like this [small window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKXlm.png) it is on normal window and this  [on large screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziB7H.png) is on 1800* width window how can i make it responsive, 
here is my code

```
               barchart(){
               //console.log(passinggroupdata);
                  //bar charts section



   this.chart = new Chart({
    // colors: ['#f8e367','#e18197','#93ccce'],
     chart: {
       //height: 200,
       width: 360,
      renderTo: 'chartcontainer',
       type: 'bar',
       plotBorderWidth: 1,
       margin: [30, 30, 60, 75]
   },

   title: {
       text: ''
   },
   xAxis: {
       categories: ['Company', 'Competitor', 'Industry']
   },
   yAxis: {
       min: 0,
       title: {
           text: ''
       }
   },
   legend: {
       reversed: true
   },


   plotOptions: {
       series: {
           stacking: 'pointer',
           point: {
            events: {
                click: function(e){
                   const p = e.point
                   this.getChartsData(p.category,p.series.name);
                   //alert(p.category);
                   //alert(p.series.name);
                }.bind(this)
            }
        }
       }
   },
```

`

Comment: Just remove `chart.width = 360`. Highcharts by default use 100% of the container. Check demos: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x1ydrjuk/

Comment: after removing it is out of the frame and overflow also

Comment: Could you reproduce it somehow? Perhaps the chart container overflows the parent container and the chart takes 100% of it?

Comment: i used this <div class="chart d-flex h-100 flex-scroll widget-content"> to control its height else it's height is overflowing

Comment: Try to prepare a simplified demo with this issue, please. I don't know what these classes actually do.